# TypeScript | JavaScript | Angular 2 | @Output vs @Input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, output, eventemitter

## Whyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy?

Dear Reader,

I've searched high and low, but nobody can explain this without a huge leap of faith to just say, "Here are the effects!", or "This is how you do that! Don't ask why!"

### The issue

```
class ChildComponent {
    @Output selected: EventEmitter<T>() = EventEmitter<T>();
    @Input item;
    handleClick(e, t) {
        ...
        this.selected.emit(t);
    }
}
```

---

```
class ParentComponent {
    items = [];
    handleSelection(type) {
        ...
    }
}
```

#### Parent Template

```
<child-component [item]="item" (selected)="handleSelection(item)" *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{item.name}}
</child-component>
```

For whatever reason, nobody can explain this syntax in anything remotely abstract. Every answer is so unbearably *concrete* that any meaning is lost outside of the specificity of defining events at the component level, where only the direct parent has access -- and, there's virtually *no reason whatsoever* to use `@Output`/`EventEmitter` instead of `@Input`/`callback`.

### Question

`@Output isThisAUselessVariable;`
Given that this "output" is undefined -- moreover, has nothing to do with `EventEmitter` -- what in Poseidon's sake would I do with this? At this point, what can I even use it for? Is it utterly useless now? What if it has a value, but the value is an `Array` or an `Object`? What about a `String`? **How may I use `@Output` *without* using `EventEmitter`?**

That *seems* like odd questioning here, but I want to avoid answers of "Because you can use it for events. If you want an event, use this! This is how you do events! Why??? I don't know! Just remember the magic event syntax!"

### Further Questions & Curiosities

A)

Why the nomenclature "@Output"? What makes it an "output"?

---

B)

Aside from potential benefits of *Message Coupling*, why not use `@Input` with callbacks?

---

C)

Is messaging the only reason why I'd use `@Output`? What else is/can it be used for? [ SEE 'A' ]

---

D)

Who can listen for this event? Can a great-grandparent listen without having to pass in a handler directly to the child/great-grandchild and manually bubble it? [ SEE 'B' ]

---

E)

I'm used to messaging being global or bubbling, and *well-designed* Event-Driven Architectures to define Event-Types at the Application-Scale -- not the Component-Scale. This allows for different types of "*Message Filtering*" (SEE Wikipedia), and allows us to use an Application Mediator.

Why would I *want* to use this at the component scale? How can I define events on a higher scale and use them on a lower scale?

---

F)

How can I *mediate* these events? [ SEE 'E' ]

---

Tons of Appreciation,

Cody

Comment: “and, there's virtually no reason whatsoever to use `@Output`/`EventEmitter` instead of `@Input`/`callback`” How about all the usual reasons for using events instead of callbacks, e.g. if you need a number of listeners that is not 1?

Comment: Personal recommendation - I'd suggest asking questions instead of making criticisms: *"This is wrong. Why would someone make something wrong?"* won't really motivate anyone to take the time to answer a question, let alone a 6 part question.

Comment: This question is wayyyyyyyyyyyyyyy too broad...

Comment: Also, make your title something other than a bunch of keywords; see [ask].

Comment: Mike, I think you mean *in-depth*. Broad would be something like, "how do I use TypeScript?", which has a lot of breadth. This question just regards @Output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you annotate a variable with @Output it has to be of  the type EventEmitter. The name of the variable becomes the name of the custom event. Messaging is the only reason for using @Output. You're sending an event without caring who's interested in getting it. Angular doesn't support event bubbling, but you can implement it with native DOM events.

IMO, using events offers a more loosely coupled architecture in inter-component communication than passing callbacks. In this blog I showed how to use callbacks with @Input params: https://yakovfain.com/2016/10/31/angular-2-component-communication-with-events-vs-callbacks/

In this video I showed one of the ways of mediating using @Input, @Output, and the parent component as a mediator: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSXx4NoKEYY
Using an injectable service as a mediator offers more flexibility though.

Comment: What an excellent answer. This really, really helps!